Application load test with k6
I want to make load test on my node js application using k6. Used nest js framework.
Here is my script
import { sleep } from 'k6';
import http from 'k6/http';
 export const options = {
      vus: 3000,
      duration: '30s',
 };
 export default function () {
    http.get('https://www........com/');
    sleep(1);
 } 

I have highly configured server resource. k6 resulted success / okay on 2000 vus. but if I use more then that it shows
error="Get "https://..........com/": read tcp 192.111.10.246:57594->20.191.222.204:443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
I also tested with renowned online portal by following above script for checking my script. But same error occurred.
Whenever I tried with more then 3000 vus it shows request time out , An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host .......
What it the reason behind that ? How can I load test my application.
My expectation is to make capable of my application is 30000 concurrent user request at a time.

Does the server that runs your application allow more than 3000 concurrent connection? (and all components between your load generator host and the service host). This sounds like a network problem rather than an application problem.

https://grafana.com/docs/k6/latest/testing-guides/running-large-tests/ might be helpful
